# Issues with using threading and multiprocessing python libraries?

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing

How bad is it to create multiple processes and make those processes create threads. My task is both I/O and cpu bound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the specifics of your workload. For parallelizing CPU-bound work in Python, you should absolutely be using the `multiprocessing` module. Generally you should be using as many processes as you have CPU cores. If you use any more than that, you end up hurting performance because your OS has to do more context switching to give CPU time to each process.

Things are complicated somewhat by the addition of I/O-bound work. Generally, it's ok to handle I/O-bound work with `threading` in Python, because the GIL will be released while blocking I/O calls occur. However, it's important to remember that everything else that goes on in that thread will require the GIL - once the I/O operation completes, bubbling it back up into Python from the C-code that ran it, passing that data somewhere to be processed, looping back around to make the blocking I/O call again, etc. All that requires the GIL. So there is a GIL-related performance cost to using threads, even for I/O-bound operations. If your I/O-bound threads that are reading from a socket are frequently getting data, they'll end up needing to acquire the GIL quite a bit, which will probably have a noticeable impact on performance. If your I/O-bound thread spends most of its time blocking, it will spend most of its time without the GIL, and probably won't have a noticeable performance impact.

So TL;DR- it might be fine to do what you're describing, or it might not. It's *extremely* dependent on the specifics of your workload. Really, your best option is to try it out and see how performance looks, then make tweaks to the number of processes/threads you're running and compare.

Comment: Well, things do perform significantly better as compared to running the task sequentially. We, sometimes miss a few `Redis` calls somewhere. Without any exceptions being raised. That's quite weird!

Comment: @user3848191 Are the redis calls happening in `apply_async` or `map_async` calls? Exceptions occurring in those will happen silently unless you call `get` on the `AsynResult` objects that get returned.